# Obj-C: Difference between "Fairfield" and @"Fairfield" (with at string)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I just had a ridonkulous typo in my iPhone app, [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656287).

Now I'm wondering about the @"..." notation.

why this works:

```
NSArray *someArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Fairfield", nil];
```

and this does not (even though it compiles, it will throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS):

```
NSArray *someArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: "@Fairfield", nil];
```

**Edit:**

Ok, so you guys have pointed out that I can't add a C string to an NSArray, because it's obviously not an object.

Now another question: Isn't this somewhat of an oversight?  I mean, why does the "...WithObjects:" message specify a list of (id) instead of (NSObject *)?

Comment: This is just a clarification of your previous question, and should have been edited into that one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656287/beginner-why-do-i-get-a-exc-bad-access

Comment: Thanks Paul - I did think about editing it - but I figured this was more general and more informative than pointing out a silly typo.  I'll lean towards the other option in the future.

Comment: The oversight is entirely yours. Descendance from NSObject is safely assumed in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Fairfield"` is a C string, `@"Fairfield"` is an Objective-C string.

`@"Fairfield"` is an object (NSString), so you can send it methods (`[@"Fairfield" uppercaseString]`) and add it to Objective-C arrays (`[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fairfield",nil]`). You can only add objects to NSArrays.

On the other hand, `"Fairfield"` is a C string, and is generally not used in Cocoa. For the most part, you can get by with only using `@"Fairfield"`

Answer (score 10):

`"@Fairfield"` is a normal C string with an '@' character in it. `@"Fairfield"` is an Objective-C string (`NSString` on OS X) with no literal '@' in it.

You cannot add C strings to Cocoa collections.

Answer (score 4):

It accepts `id` rather than `NSObject` because all initialisers return `id`. All initialisers return `id` because subclasses would otherwise override the return type of their ancestors' initialisers.

For example, `-[NSMutableString init]` can't return `NSMutableString *` because it subclasses `-[NSString init]`, which can't return `NSString *` because it overrides `-[NSObject init]`.

Unfortunately, implicit type-casting between `const char *` and `id` is perfectly legit, so the compiler won't throw a warning, however a static analyser may be able to pick this sort of mishap up fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Very helpful.  Too bad the analyzer in XCode doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

The other reason that a number of things in Cocoa deal with `id` rather than `NSObject*` is because, unlike some other languages (say, Java and C#), where all objects in the language must inherit from some global base class, it's entirely possible to have objects that do not descend from `NSObject` (`NSProxy` being one example). It's not something you'd do often, but it is possible. The `id` type means "pointer to any Objective C instance".

Comment: Ahhhh... so this explains the reasoning for id.  I had assumed that all NS* objects descended from NSObject.

Comment: In general, it's pretty safe to assume that they are. (Along with the non-NS* framework classes.) But it's not a rule that they *must* be.